# can scrapy scrape contents of iframe using scrapy alone?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

[image: iframe code]

I've tried copy and pasting the elements(xpath) of the site but returns no result.

can scrapy scrape data that is inside the iframe? if yes how and if not, what other things should be done? thanks!

```
rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = path_deny_base, restrict_xpaths=('*'))
    , callback="parse", follow= True),
    )


    def parse(self, response):
        yield(Request(url, callback = self.parse_iframe))

    def parse_iframe(self, response):
        #your code to scrape the content from iframe
        #def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//div[2]/h1')
            #//div[2]/h1
        linker = hxs.select('//div[2]/div[10]/a[1]')
            #//div[2]/div[10]/a[1]
        loc_Con = hxs.select('//div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]') #//div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]
        loc_Reg = hxs.select('//div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[2]') #/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[2]
        loc_Loc = hxs.select('//div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[3]') #/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span/span/span[3]
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            #item ["job_id"] = id.select('text()').extract()[0].strip()
            item ["title"] = map(unicode.strip, titles.select('text()').extract()) #ok
            item ["link"] = linker.select('@href').extract() #ok
            item ["info"] = (response.url)
            temp1 = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()
            temp2 = loc_Reg.select('text()').extract()
            temp3 = loc_Loc.select('text()').extract()
            temp1 = temp1[0] if temp1 else ""
            temp2 = temp2[0] if temp2 else ""
            temp3 = temp3[0] if temp3 else ""
            item["code"] = "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(temp1, temp2, temp3)
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

Answer (score 6):

Scrapy can not scrape the content from the iframe. Rather you make request to iframe URL, like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield(Request(url, callback = self.parse_iframe))

def parse_iframe(self, response):
    #your code to scrape the content from iframe
```

Where, url should be iframe url, for example `https://career-meridia....../jobs)`

**Edit:**

Replace the url with red-underlined part.
[image: Put the underlined part]
**Edit2:**
Make sure you have passed every param that needed by iframe url. Otherwise you will get nothing. If it is post method, you have to pass all the post param.

Comment: in case i wanted to get the Environmental service aide, will the normal xpath do?

Comment: It sure do if you get response for that child iframe (make request as I shown above)

Comment: It is hard to read your code here, can you edit your questions with this code. thanks

Comment: you have to replace url with value iframe src above.

Comment: iframe src? sorry, I don't really get it. I tried changing url to response.url. it show output but not right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55896/discussion-between-krishna-sunuwar-and-chano).

Comment: That won't always work. For example, here trying to open iframe url you will get redirected back to the original page with an iframe. Adding `meta={"dont_redirect": True}` might be needed.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way i'm doing it. First get the iframe url, then call parse again on it.

```
urls = response.css('iframe::attr(src)').extract()
for url in urls :
        yield scrapy.Request(url....)
```